# How to move the SharePoint's SQL Server Instance from one Server to Another

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-database, sql-server-2012

Am having a single server farm for my SP 2013, currently WFE is installed on **Server01** and  sql db in **Server02** . I dont have sufficient space in server02, where sql server is running, like no D:\ drive no E:\ drive. It has only  9 GB left, shows in  red color.

Now I wanna restore a SharePoint content db thats having size of 15 GB.

Is there any way, I can move the compete  sql db instance from one server to another server that has enough space?

Do i need to reconfigure in WFE central admin such that, it points to a  new server.t

Answer (score 1):

Install\ Configure SQL Server on Server 3, and make server 2 and server as Always on\Clustering\ Mirroring which ever is possible for your case. Test the FARM status by turning off the server 2, and once you confirm the server is up, you can remove the server completely.